# A class of probability sequences going to zero?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Suppose I have a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ defined on some probability space, **with $\boldsymbol{\textbf{supp}(X_n)}$ a discrete set, $\boldsymbol{\textbf{supp}(X_n)}$ uniformly bounded, and $\boldsymbol{|\textbf{supp}(X_n)|}$ strictly increasing in $\boldsymbol{n}$**. I also have a sequence of sets $\{\mathcal{E}_1\supset \cdots\supset \mathcal{E}_n\supset\cdots\}$, strictly decreasing to the empty set $\emptyset$. Is it true that 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n\in \mathcal{E}_n) = 0,
\end{equation*}
or are there interesting counter-examples? (Note that $\mathscr{A}_n=\{X_n\in\mathcal{E}_n\}$ need not be a decreasing collection of events, so straightforward arguments do not work here.)

If we let $a_n=\mathbb{P}(X_n\in \mathcal{E}_n)$, it seems like the strictly decreasing condition on the $\mathcal{E}_n$'s and the strictly increasing support size condition on $X_n$ are jointly forcing $a_n$ to eventually converge to $0$, but I am having trouble constructing a general argument.

*Edit:* `@stochasticboy321` *posted a counter-example without assuming uniform boundedness of the support. I modified the question above to include that extra condition. A related question I have in mind is, **under what extra conditions does the above limit hold**?*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take $\mathcal{E}_n$ to be the naturals bigger than $n$, and let $X_n$ be supported on $[n+1:2n]$. Then $P(X_n \in \mathcal{E}_n) = 1$ for every $n$, so the limit is $1$.

Comment: Nice! Ok, I am going to rephrase my question, since the setup I had in mind is slightly different and I've clearly not included all the constraints.

Comment: Reciprocals of stochasticboy's example should still work.

Comment: Yes, I realize that taking support of $X_n$ to be $\{1,1/2,...,1/n\}$ and placing mass $0.5$ on $1/n$ and distributing mass equally among rest, while setting $\mathcal{E}_n=(0,1/n]$, works. It seems like some kind of constraint on the entropy of $X_n$ or on the pmf of $X_n$ is needed?